# How do I cut a trace?

Tags: pcb, tools, rework

I've often had the need to cut a trace here and there to debug something or fix a bad layout. I've not really come up on a way to do so that's

- Safe
- Controllable
- Reliable (won't magically reconnect if something touches it)

I've tried X-actos, Dremels with cutoff wheels or tiny burrs, and bludgeoning them with a hot iron (usually to remove a segment so I'm sure it can't reconnect), but it always feels really hacky. One wrong move with a Dremel and you're slicing the electrolytic cap that's only slightly crowding you. Knives usually require some sawing, which requires a lot of force, which is not how to knife, generally.

(black-and-white-infomercial-failure.gif)

There must be a better way...

Comment: I use an X-acto for trace widths up to about 25 mils, a Dremel for anything much thicker.

Comment: Do you control the design of the PCB in any meaningful way? If so, consider adding zero-ohm resistors on any traces you anticipate might need to be disconnected for testing or modding purposes.

Comment: A Dremel drill press kit works great for low-density two-layer boards, drilling at the center of a trace consistently and reliably disconnects it. Unfortunately it doesn't work for high-density board with 6-mil traces or multi-layer boards.

Comment: They make tiny grinding pens for removing solder mask and/or copper traces under a microscope.

Comment: I use a dental pick that I ground to a blade type tip.

Comment: This question is _not_ complete without a link to PACE's absolutely awesome and over-the-top [Adventures in Repair](https://youtu.be/hzZuryFmPo0) - Follow our hero Wembly on an intergalactic multi-layer PCB repair adventure!

Comment: @比尔盖子 a drill press actually sounds like a pretty good idea over free-handing with a cutoff wheel.

Comment: @user1850479 can you post some example images/search terms?

Comment: @NickT A drill press and a set of PCB drill bits were how I made home-etched boards when I first got into electronics. 1.4 / 0.7 mm vias was the smallest size I could drill.

Comment: Example of grinding pen for traces (and even opening IC packages): https://youtu.be/pSuaS11QeWY

Comment: @pipe I don't know what their "micro sheen unit" is (their Dremel), but I wonder if just getting a crappy/off-brand/less-powerful rotary tool that's more dexterous than a huge one is probably more than sufficient to cut copper foil with a ball mill.

Comment: @user1850479 if only it was an answer... `:(`

Comment: Product recommendations are discouraged, and I have no experience with that specific device so I don't want to make this an answer which would imply it's a good solution. Rather I think it's helpful to point out that this class of device exists and other people use them in case you want to check them out or do more research. Personally I use a knife under a stereo scope which is fine for prototypeing, if a little slow.

Comment: @user1850479 if only there was an answer that described that class of device `:(`

Answer (score 12):

The OP has mentioned the classic tools: Xacto knives, or Dremels if space permits.  There really isn't much more in the typical toolkit.

However, a real "force multiplier" for these tools is a binocular microscope, preferably with integrated lighting.  With one of these, the Xacto can be wielded with amazing precision, even if you've had too much coffee.  AmScope makes a lot of binocular microscopes, one of which is in my company's lab and is awesome.  A proper binocular microscope allows you to see the working area very comfortably through the eyepieces, while both of your hands can work on the item, either soldering, cutting traces, and so on.

Comment: This. A 'work' microscope, low magnification stereo with long distance to the focus, increases your own optical feedback gain, and you can cut very precisely.

Comment: +1. I have used a stereoscopic microscope with two cameras & two projectors, it projects on a parabolic mirror in front of the user. The end effect is that you see in 3d, suspended just before your eyes, several 10x bigger. This tool enables me to consistently rework 0402 and 0201 components, while without any aid I am just able to work with 0603 and perhaps barely touch up 0402.

Comment: This. I've done some incredibly fine PCB mods (some after removing the top layer to get at an inner layer) with nothing more than a sharp 10A scalpel, and some IPA to keep the area clean.

Comment: Even a simple OptiVisor helps muchly.

Comment: I've had very good experiences with "dental loupes" which sell for upwards of $2000 for the Name Brands.  However perfectly serviceable knockoffs are available from popular online retailers for under $100.

Answer (score 1):

The real trick is using a microscope, I think that is essential to see where you are cutting. If using an xacto cut two slices of where you want to cut then use a flat blade precision screwdriver to dig out the copper in between the marks, using a screwdriver allows you to use a scraping motion and take the trace out in a more controlled manner.

Or you can use the screwdriver just on it's own but I usually use a combination of both.

If you need to get to a trace in an inner layer to cut a trace, you can use a precision milling bit or a flat blade screwdriver (yep a flat blade can make a pretty round hole!) and twist until you see the top of the other trace. Then keep cutting and checking until you see FR4 again.

Answer (score 0):

A scalpel/xacto blade (preferably new, fresh and sharp) can be used in a drill-like motion to cut the trace, rather than a cutting motion. Place the tip of the blade on the trace, press down lightly and twist the knife. The tip will dig in and cut the trace. Be careful not to go too deep on multi-layer boards!

Compared to a cutting motion, this technique means there's less chance of slipping and cutting adjacent traces and it also makes the break wider.